# How to install perl rename on Alpine?

Tags: file-rename, alpine-linux

I want to be able to use a regex to perform file renaming so `rename` from [util-linux](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/main/x86_64/util-linux) is not good while `perl-rename` (also call `prename`) could make it.

Unfortunately, I didn't find any "perl-rename" package in Alpine repository...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this (from `testing` repository):

```
apk add perl-file-rename --repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing/
```

Check https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/727288/12574

Usage:

```
file-rename --help
```

Answer (score 0):

One workaround, would be to use `sed` and `mv` as replacement, e.g.:

```bash
for old in *.whl; do
    new=$(echo "$old" | sed -e "s/\(ortools-[0-9\.]\+\)/\1+musl/")
    mv -v -- "$old" "$new"
done
```